# Checking the maximality of a principal ideal in $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $R = \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ be the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal generated by $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then prove that the ideal generated by $(2x-1)$ is maximal in $R[x]$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** Prove that $R[x]/(2x-1)\simeq R[\frac12]$ and $R[\frac12]=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I like the example and explanation. It bugged me so much since the ideal $(2x -1)$ is a principal maximal ideal in a two dimensional regular ring. It'd be nice if someone can explain a bit more on this phenomenon.

Comment: @Youngsu You can find more details [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99343/is-xy-1-a-maximal-ideal-in-kxy?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

The above hint is correct. Sending $x$ to $1/2$ we get a surjective map from $R[x]$ to $\mathbb Q$ and then look kernel of this homomorphism that will be exactly $(2x-1)$. So we are done.