# Let $R$ be an integral domain which is not a field. Then can $R[x]$ have a maximal ideal generated by a non-constant polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be an integral domain which is not a field. Then is it true that $\langle f \rangle$ cannot be a maximal ideal of $R[x]$ for any non-constant polynomial $f(x) \in R[x]$ ?

I know that it holds in case of $R=\mathbb Z$ and I can adapt the proof to draw similar conclusion in case $R$ is a UFD with infinitely many mutually  non-associated prime elements. But I don't know what happens in general. If the answer in general is not true then does it at least hold if we also assume $R$ is Noetherian ?

Comment: How about $R = \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \{ a/b \text{ such that } a, b\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } \operatorname{gcd}(b, p) = 1\}$ and $f(x) = px-1$, with $R[x]/f(x) = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99343/is-xy-1-a-maximal-ideal-in-kxy?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752342/checking-the-maximality-of-a-principal-ideal-in-rx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field, and let $R=K[[y]]$.  Consider the polynomial $f=xy-1$ in $R[x]$.  Then the quotient $R/\langle f \rangle$ is isomorphic to $K[[y]][x]/\langle xy-1\rangle$, which is a field (it is isomorphic to the field of fractions of $K[[y]]$).

Thus the ideal $\langle f \rangle$ can be maximal.

Comment: I have just seen the comment of @anon to the question, which in spirit gives the same kind of example as in my answer.

Comment: The "spirit" means here that $R$ is a DVR, and $y$ is an uniformizer.