# $\dim(R/x) = \dim(R)-1$ for Noetherian integral domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a Noetherian integral domain of finite Krull-dimension and $0 \neq x \in R$ a non-unit. Do we have $\dim(R/x) = \dim(R) -1$ in general?

If this is wrong, does it change something if we further assume that $R$ is positively graded, finitely generated by homogeneous elements of degree one over $R_0$, which is Artinian local, and $x$ is homogeneous of degree one?

Context: This dimension formula is used [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&lpg=PA175&ots=XmSfyKcQW4&dq=bruns%20herzog%20theorem%204.1.3&hl=de&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q=bruns%20herzog%20theorem%204.1.3&f=false).

Comment: You should also require $x$ to be non-unit, otherwise $R / (x) \cong \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Of course you are right. I edited my question.

Comment: See KING LIU's Book , pages $71-72$

Comment: @Hamou: Do you mean Lemma 5.13? The other results on those pages are about local rings.

Comment: The additional assumption that we want is for $R$ to be catenary.  Then this follows from Krull's principal ideal theorem.

Comment: @you-sir-33433: catenary is not quite enough - see the example in the linked answer in my post. However, it does suffice that $x$ is in the Jacobson radical of $R$

Comment: @zcn You are right.  I believe I was thinking of equidimensionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $\dim R/(x)$ can be $< \dim R - 1$ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/799675/115654). However it does hold if $R$ is (in addition) local. Thus in the specific setting, where $R$ is a standard graded Noetherian domain (so that $R_0$ is a field, not just Artinian), then if $\DeclareMathOperator{\m}{\mathfrak{m}}$$\m$ is the homogeneous maximal ideal (which is maximal), we have $\dim R - 1 = \dim R_m - 1 = \dim R_m/xR_m = \dim (R/x)_m = \dim R/(x)$ (since $\dim R = {}^*\!\dim R$ if $R$ is positively graded with $R_0$ local).

Comment: Thank you very much! I just don't understand why you want to assume that $R_0$ is a field. Doesn't your argumentation hold as well for $R_0$ Artinian local, since then we also have a unique homogeneous maximal ideal?

Comment: It's true that there is a unique homogeneous maximal ideal if $R_0$ is only assumed Artinian local. But if $R$ is a domain, then $R_0 \subseteq R$ is also a domain, hence will be a field

Comment: Of course you are right. Thanks again!